# How to compare performance between Javascript and CSS animation solutions?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building an app where animation performance matters a lot. I built a javascript solution for animations/transitions. Then I built the same solution written in Javascript + CSS, and then I built the same solution using pure CSS.

Now I want to compare them to see which is more performing. I've been comfortable using performance.now() to benchmark pure javascript code, like this:

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

This works pretty well. But now when animations comes into the mix, I'm not sure how to compare it. All of the solutions have an animation that take 750 ms to complete, so using timing doesn't really work as I'm not really trying to measure accuracy but system toll.

How to benchmark this? Is there a tool that would 'cripple' my browser processing power so I can simulate the same solutins in less powerful cpus?

Comment: You might use `Performance` and `Memory` tabs in your browser's Developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to audit your page and inspect the rendering and see if it's hitting the 60fps mark. And if there are differences between the pure CSS and js solutions.

---

You can use the frame rate of an animation to measure how responsive an application feels. 60 frames per second is the generally accepted target for achieving a “natural” feel.

[image]